# HTML Document type and XML namespace

Tags: html, xml

I understand that in order to instruct the browser how to handle HTML page I need to specify a DOCTYPE... For a page that i built with HTML5 I used the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

When i am viewing other sites that are using the same DOCTYPE, there is an additional definition inside the `<html>` tag, such as:

```
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

What does the xml namespace do that it is needed inside the HTML tag in addition to the DOCTYPE definition?

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `xmlns` attribute is set, it's a XHTML (XHTML5) document.

This indicates a HTML5 document:

```
HTTP-Header Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

And this indicates a XHTML5 document:

```
HTTP-Header Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

If the webpage is using XHTML5 an does not have the `xmlns` attribute, it wont be displayed properly (Firefox would display the XML-DOM instead of the page).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 isn't XML, so the informations in the html tag aren't needed

Comment: Thanks, for the sake of my understanding - if i was using XHTML, I would write "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">"  but then I would also write <html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> . Why is that?

Comment: Each XML document must have a namespace in order to "find" the elements you can use in the DTD. It's really like a namespace in other programming languages.